# MPI Gather returning incorrect values

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I've come to seek help with my issue.

The whole below code seems to return proper values for root process, but incorrect values like -1.#IND00 for all other processes.  Also Barriers don't work, before I generate the arrays and broadcast them, some of the processes freely go over.

The main idea is to put different parts of vector into other processes and then to glue them into one variable with MPI_Gather.

I have no idea where I have gone wrong.

I'll be grateful for any help given.

```
double *xNowe = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
double *vec = calloc(n/size, sizeof(double));

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(A, n*n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(b, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(x0, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
while(delta > granica)
{
    ii++;
    for(i = mystart; i < myend; i++)
    {
        vec[i - mystart] = b[i];
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(i != j)
            {
                vec[i - mystart] -= A[i][j] * x0[j];
            }
        }
        vec[i - mystart] = vec[i - mystart] / A[i][i];
        if(rank > 0)
            printf("\n%f", vec[i - mystart]);
        }
        printf("1: %d, 10: %d, 50: %d, 110: %d, 200: %d, 300: %d, 400: %d",xNowe[1],xNowe[10],xNowe[110],xNowe[200],xNowe[300],xNowe[400]);
        MPI_Allgather(vec, n/size, MPI_DOUBLE, xNowe, n/size, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        if(rank == 0)
        {
            delta = 0;
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                delta = delta + ((xNowe[i] - x0[i] > 0) ? (xNowe[i] - x0[i]) : (-(xNowe[i] - x0[i])));
            }

            //x0 = xNowe; nie dzialalo
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                x0[i] = xNowe[i];
            }
        }
        MPI_Bcast(&delta, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(x0, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}
```

Update: The loop crashes at 2nd iteration with value calculated on certain indexes of xNowe as:

```
1: 1204749721, 10: -1085549499, 50: -1034011523, 110: 1063725393, 200: -17690801
07, 300: -1083408896, 400: -5847835510
1: 0, 10: -524288, 50: 0, 110: -524288, 200: 0, 300: -524288, 400: 0
```

Comment: What are you expecting the barriers to do? They don't seem to accomplish anything here.

Comment: Thanks for editing my code to look more appropriate. Those barriers are supposed to make processes wait till they receive broadcasted values. To be honest I have no idea what might be an issue.

Comment: You don't need barriers to make processes wait after the calls to `mpi_bcast`.  Those are *collective* calls, all the processes in the specified communicator participate in them.  The observable behaviour should be that the processes participate simultaneously and that all processes finish their participation before continuing to the next executable statement.  I don't see that the presence of an unnecessary barrier as the source of your problem though.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Still seems like some values aren't passed or are passed badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MPI_Gather()` gathers values on proc `root`. If you wish to gather values everywhere, you may use `MPI_Allgather()`

http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Allgather.html

Bye,

Francis

Comment: Well, that still doesn't solve the problem. Seems like barriers not workin is the main issue.

Comment: `mpi_gather` gathers onto whichever process one programs it to gather onto.  The 7th argument in the call specifies what process that is.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : i apologize for being unclear. @user1794121 : How do you allocate the matrix `A` ? Would you mind trying to give `&A[0][0]` to the first `MPI_Bast()` ?

Comment: You're answer is not unclear but the first sentence is incorrect.

Comment: It seems like broadcasts started working with &x0[0] and &b[0]. They only seem not to work with the matrix. (currently trying to convert matrix to vector by specifying indexes. Seems to work so far.

Comment: Not exactly above answer, but the comment involving &A[0][0] from the author has helped me in identifying my issue of badly broadcasted values.